# Регулярное выражение (A-Z, a-z, А-Я, а-я, знаки апострофа и тире)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Привет Всем! Как написать регулярное выражение на javascript таким образом чтобы допускались только слова A-Z, a-z, А-Я, а-я и знаки апострофа и тире.
Вот пытался сделать, но к сожалению не работает правильно

```
 /^[a-zA-Z\u0410-\u042F\u0430-\u044F_]+$/g;
```

Вот тут где-то пролемма, что не вводи оно видает true

```
$("#family").change(function(){
    family = $("#family").val();
    var expfamily =  /^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F`]+$/; 
    var resfamily = family.search(expfamily);
    if(resfamily == -1){
        $("#family").next().hide().text("Поле должно содержать только символы.").css("padding-left","5px","color","red").fadeIn(400);
        $("#family").removeClass().addClass("inputRed");
        familyStat = 0;
        buttonOnAndOff();
    }
    if(family.length < 3){
        $("#family").next().hide().text("Поле содержит мало символов.").css("padding-left","5px","color","red").fadeIn(400);
        $("#family").removeClass().addClass("inputRed");
        familyStat = 0;
        buttonOnAndOff();
    }else{
        $("#family").removeClass().addClass("inputGreen");
        $("#family").next().text("");
        familyStat = 1;
        buttonOnAndOff();
    }   
});
$("#family").keyup(function(){
    $("#family").removeClass();
    $("#family").next().text("");
});
```

Comment: в какой кодировке находится исходник javascript и в какой кодировке вы отдаёте страницу ?

Comment: Не нашел проблемы:

    console.log(/^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F]+$/.test('!"№;%:?*('));
    console.log(/^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F]+$/.test('asd-'));
    console.log(/^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F]+$/.test('авыаА'));

> false
> true
> true

Скорее всего, проблема в кодировке сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
re = /^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F`]+$/;
```

Comment: Всеравно пишу "!"№;%:?*(" оно выдает что все нормально в проверки Работало только с латиницей

Comment: В браузере `javascript:alert(/^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F\']+$/.test("ааа"));`работает. Так что проверьте у себя браузер, кодировки, опечатки.

Comment: @Node_pro, Как вы пишите?)

    re = /^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F`]+$/;
    alert( re.test('"!"№;%:?*("') ); //Выводит false

Comment: Вот смотрите добавил фрагмент гд-то может ошибка

Comment: Так вы неверно используете!

Вместо:

    var expfamily =  /^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F`]+$/; 
    var resfamily = family.search(expfamily);

Надо:

    var expfamily =  /^[-a-zA-Z\u0410-\u044F`]+$/; 
    var resfamily = expfamily.test( family );

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:
/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\'\-]+/g

или

/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\u0410-\u042F\u0430-\u044F\_]+/g;

Comment: Всеравно пишу "!"№;%:?*(" оно выдает что все нормально в проверки
Работало только с латиницей

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так /[A-Za-zА-Яа-я'-]*/
Вообще есть хороший ресурс для тестирования регулярок js: [вот](http://regexpal.com/).